# immutable class requirement scenarios

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have recently understood the concept of immutable class. I have also understood the concept of how to make the class immutable.  But I just want to know are there any specific scenarios in our Java Project implementation where usage of the immutable class is absolutely necessary. In other words are there scenarios where it is compulsory to use the user defined immutable class?

Comment: No, it just (some times) makes programming easier.

Comment: I was been asked this in one of the interviews where they want me to come up with the specific scenarios  where immutability is compulsory

Comment: This is far too broad of a question for SO. It *may* be more appropriate for Programmers SE, but I don't participate there and cannot say for sure.

Comment: @Brian so you want me to post this question in programmers stack exchange???

Comment: Slow down.  I'm not sure this is a particularly broad question, nor am I sure it's a particularly useful question on Programmers.SE.

Comment: @Makoto I mean, the short answer is "No". And the right answer is a chapter on design ... I don't see how either fits here is all.

Comment: Read Effective Java Item 15 : Minimize Mutability.

Comment: @n1234 thanks I will look in to it right now.

Comment: @Beast That book ('Effective Java' by Josh Bloch) is a must-read for anyone serious about Java and the section cited by n1234 does cover this well.

Comment: @Brian I have gone through the topic and understood the immutability concept. But I am looking for specific scenario where you can use immutability

Comment: I know, which is why I said it was a bit broad for SO. There are numerous scenarios where you *can* use it but the reason to do so is purely one of a design decision. There is no compulsory scenario (which is why I mentioned the short answer was "no"). For example there's a lot of traction around simplifying concurrent programming by using immutable objects. The issue is always one of a trade-off between performance (you tend to do a lot of copying when using immutable data structures) and safety (in terms of not writing bugs due to concurrency and mutable objects).  That's just one example.

Comment: @Beast I could probably spend an hour writing up what I'd consider a proper answer to your question (I don't think it's a bad question) but I still don't know that I could provide what would be considered a canonical answer on the subject which is (in theory) what an SO answer is supposed to do. Not trying to be rude or anything.

Answer (score 0):

There are two major reasons why, I think, you may want to use immutability. One is to simplify reasoning about a program execution and second to make concurrent programming more efficient and easier.

I would start with two ways of how an object can be immutable in Java.

One would be an effectively immutable object, which once constructed will not modify its state.

Second type would be an object immutable in terms of guarantees of Java Memory Model and concurrent programming, I mean here an object which have all of its fields marked `final`, and having its `this` reference not escaping during the object construction.

## Reason about execution

Both immutability kinds share the property of making the program easier to reason about. For example using a mutable object as a key in a Map doesn't seem like a good idea. Consider a class Storage, which keeps users' age.

```
class Storage {
    private Map<User, Integer> age = new HashMap<>();

    public void put(User name, Integer userAge) {
        age.put(name, userAge);
    }

    public Integer get(User name) {
        return age.get(name);
    }

}
```

And a User class being mutable.

```
class User {
    private String name;

    User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void toUpperCase() {
        name = name.toUpperCase();
    }

    // consider hashCode and Equals to be correctly 
    // implemented and delegate to `name`

}
```

It's easy to achieve a situation, where you will not be able to find your user's age anymore.

```
    Storage storage = new Storage();

    User john = new User("John");
    storage.put(john, 25);

    System.out.println(storage.get(new User("John")));

    // we modify the reference which is used as a key in our map
    john.toUpperCase(); 
    System.out.println(john.getName());

    System.out.println(storage.get(new User("John")));
```

This is rather simple case, and it's easy to spot an error, but in a complex program, this may lead to issues which are much harder to track. One solution would be to make defensive copies of your objects, but it's much easier to make them immutable.

## Concurrent programming

I have mentioned at the beginning that immutable objects are useful, when dealing with concurrency. You don't have to synchronize access to immutable objects once they have been safely published. There is no mutable state, so there is no race condition. This may lead to better performance and less cluttered code.

Additionally having all fields final gives you [happens-before](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5.1%20semantic) semantic. E.g. if you had an effectively immutable object of an ImmutableUser class, it could happen that other threads could see improper values of the `address` field due to [how Java Memory Model works](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4).

```
class Address {
    private final String street;

    Address(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    // getters
}

class ImmutableUser {
    private Address address;

    ImmutableUser(String street) {
        this.address = new Address(street);
    }

     // getters
}
```

Marking the `address` field `final` gives it happens-before guarantee, meaning that once the ImmutableUser is constructed and safely published, all the fields will have correct values seen by all threads (making address volatile or adding a synchronization would also work, and object would remain effectively immutable).